# When UITableView's data is loaded? What's time tableview call its delegate methods. After viewWillAppear?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delegates

I am wondering when `UITableview`'s data is loaded.

I mean, when I create a `UITableView`, then normally I will set its datasource and delegate. After that, this tableview will be added as a subview.

However, If I don't call `reload` method, I don't know when the tableview know it needs to ask its delegates and show the data. In another word, since a view has no `viewWillAppear` methods, what's the exact time that a tableview ask its delegate and show the data?

I've tried some what:

In `viewDidLoad`, I create a tableview, added it as subview, but not setting its delegates. Obviously, the data is not loaded.

Then I set its delegate once I tap a button, its data is not loaded.

But when the tableview's controller's `viewWillAppear` is called again (when the controller disappears and appears again), the data is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

There is no universal set time, because a UITableView's display data is in cells, and the cells are dynamically loaded. (also probably reused)  You can call reload, but that just instructs the table to refetch the data on visible cells.  The question remains: why do you need to know?  If you need to intercept the data before it's loaded into a cell, do it in cellForRowAtIndexPath, where you're supposed to stuff the data into the cell.

Comment: I am trying to understand how tableview works. Because I want to build a barChartView and mimic the same mechanism like UITableView. But despite calling reload method and fire the view to call its delegate methods, I want this barChartView can load the data once the view is appeared.

Comment: I think it's important to note that drawing is not done in real time.  When you create a UITableView, you create a set of routines that the system calls when it's ready to get data, or when it's ready to display a new cell. So most of the operation of table view is done by the system, the programmer just provides routines that the system calls when it wants to know what to put in the table.